# Spring jpa @query is not working when date value is null

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using JPA and I have used `@Query` joining of two tables, now my requirement is I can have combination of possible values in where condition, some may be null or empty.

My `@Query` contains `(value = "Select * From A a Left Outer Join B b On A.Id=B.Id where :fromDate is NULL and :toDate is NULL or B.Activity_Date_Time Between :fromDate AND :toDate")**`

I am handling this in query, it works fine for `String` but for `TIMESTAMP` is is giving an error as

> nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could
>   not extract ResultSet] with root cause
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes:
>   expected TIMESTAMP got BINARY

I have generated SQL from JPA in logs , which run fine on SQL developer

```sql
Select
        * 
    From
        table A 
    Left Outer Join
        table B 
            On A.Id=B.Id     
    Where (
            A.Customer = 'fsfsfsdfsfd'
        )    
        and (
            null is null 
            and null is null 
            or B.Activity_Date_Time Between null AND null
        ) 
        And (
            'MATURITY' is null 
            or B.Activity_Type = 'MATURITY'
        );
```

Comment: Please show us the the complete method you are using and the generated SQL. Please format both as source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your Query Parameters :fromDate and :toDate, you are passing the parameters with null value from your code. Also see your query:

```
Select
        * 
    From
        table A 
    Left Outer Join
        table B 
            On A.Id=B.Id     
    Where (
            A.Customer = 'fsfsfsdfsfd'
        )    
        and (
            null is null 
            and null is null 
            or B.Activity_Date_Time Between null AND null
        ) 
        And (
            'MATURITY' is null 
            or B.Activity_Type = 'MATURITY'
        );
```

Your named parameters are being replaced by null and if you check null with null, it will be a binary operation. Hence try to pass timestamp from code to @Query to get rid of this.

Comment: just another doubt it is working for string parameter , only for other data type it is failing.

Comment: Just because the default value null is being passed in case of your other data type, Incase please share your code.